# How to keep VPN connection alive / restrict from time out when idle?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, vpn

I am looking for various ways to keep VPN connection alive on a Unix based system when I am idle.
One way I know is run a command like "top"

```
>top
```

which continuously runs.
Is there any other way or better solution to it?

Comment: `N=1; while ((1)); echo yay $N; N=$((N+1)); sleep 6; done`?  Really, anything that will keep sending bytes.  But a VPN connection shall not die when it is idle, you likely have a firewall dropping connections after some time.

Comment: Since all of my systems run X11, I simply have an xclock being displayed through any connection I have to keep "live".  It guarantees that some amount of background traffic will always be there, but not enough to actually impact anything.  As a side benefit, if the link goes down, I can look at what time the xclock stopped updating to know when.